# How can I efficiently dedupe a very large number of records?

Tags: duplicate-contacts

I'm working on a database with about 600,000 records, of which approximately 200,000 are believed to be duplicates.

Has anyone got experience/advice for doing dedupe at scale?  I imagine that we'll need to export and do some sort of external dedupe.  Has anyone successfully used the [datamade dedupe](https://github.com/datamade/dedupe) with Civi?  I know that the "merge" API got some love a couple months ago - will any of that help me?

Answer (score 3):

We did a lot of work to the dedupe processes in CiviCRM and in 4.7 its a much easier process to de-dupe large databases then it used to be. It was presented by Eileen in this years London CiviCon, worth a look before you get into trying to do it outside of CiviCRM with all the pitfalls that brings with it!